# My Olympus Mju III 150 counter reseted. Can I still take pictures normally

Tags: film, olympus

Ok so basically I was using my camera and took a bunch of shots. I was at 28 shots out of 36. I turned off my camera but when i turned it on the film count is back at 1. Did my camera rewind its film back to the first. Or is the counter just wrong and its stil on the 28th shot and i can still take pictures normally. Please help

Answer (score 2):

The only way to know for sure is to open the back & look… which, of course, you cannot do.

If you're practised with a camera changing bag you could try by feel, but probably the safest thing to do is just consider it used & rewind it all; then send for processing.